# Fabric.js FPS test

Tags: fabricjs, frame-rate

Where can I find tests of the fabricjs rendering performance with many animated object?

I have opened this page but I can't see the current number of FPS
http://fabricjs.com/animation/

Comment: The counter in that demo wasn't fully correct, so I removed it for now. You can enable FPS counter in settings of Chrome's dev tools (I see it in v25 dev build, for example).

Comment: I have good performance on desktop.
I just wanted to test it on mobile to compare it to this:
http://jindo.dev.naver.com/collie/

Comment: @boulabiar The fabricjs is a drawing library with canvas. so I think it's not suitable for animation on mobile devices. If you want to run faster animation on mobile devices, you can use a pre-created bitmap image. For more informations about performance of the collie, you can visit [here](http://davidshimjs.github.com/collie-benchmark/)